# How to predict next login date & time from the login history of a website

Tags: regression, machine-learning, time-series, neural-networks

I've been given with login time and date of all the users and I need to predict the next login time and date of each user...

Initially, I thought I can group each user's login data and can use linear regression with date and time as individual features but I later found that I can't use it to predict both date and time, and can't even predict time on a particular day too... As I can't include seasonalities like the first week of the month there can be many logins (since it's a financial website)

Can this data can be considered as time-series data and can I use time-series algorithms like ARIMA/SARIMA but here my data consists of only time & date,  unlike Stock price data.

And how should I commit feature engineering for this dataset?
Can I use any deep learning technique?

Comment: Can you calculate the time intervals between logins for each user? If so, you could model the probability of a user logging in again given the time since the last login as Poisson-Process. You could even condition on the weekday, month, etc.

Comment: 1) It would probably make sense to model logins as a [point process](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_process). ARIMA doesn't really make sense here. 2) When formulating the model, think about what influences (and does not influence) users to log in when they do. E.g. day of the week, time of day, time since last login, history of recent logins, etc. Use as much domain knowledge as you can to decide which features to include (and exclude).